# Concurrency-safe map of slices

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a type that contains a `sync.Map` where the key in the map is a string and the value is a slice. My code for inserting items into the map is as follows:

```
newList := []*Item{item}
if result, ok := map.LoadOrStore(key, newList); ok {
    resultList := result.([]*Item)
    resultList = append(resultList, item)
    map.Store(key, resultList)
}
```

This is not concurrency-safe because the the slice can be loaded and modified by multiple calls concurrently. This code is very fragile so I've attempted to modify it to be:

```
newList := []*Item{item}
if result, ok := map.LoadOrStore(key, &newList); ok {
    resultList := result.(*[]*Item)
    *resultList = append(*resultList, item)
}
```

All this does is make the issues occur deterministically. So, I'm trying to find a way to have a map-of-slices that can be added to concurrently. My instinct is to use `sync.Mutex` to lock the list while I'm adding to it but in order to maintain the concurrent access to the `sync.Map` I would need to create a map of `sync.Mutex` objects as well, like this:

```
newLock := sync.Mutex{}
raw, _ := lockMap.LoadOrStore(key, &newLock)
lock := raw.(*sync.Mutex)

newList := []*Item{item}
if result, ok := map.LoadOrStore(key, &newList); ok {
    lock.Lock()
    resultList := result.(*[]*Item)
    *resultList = append(*resultList, item)
    lock.Unlock()
}
```

Is there an easier way to go about this?

Comment: How about a map of `struct { *sync.Mutex, []*Item }`?

Comment: @phonaputer That's an interesting solution. I hadn't thought of that

Comment: Well, it's not too different from your current idea. But it is nice to be able to do something like `SafeItems.Lock()` using the embedded `*sync.Mutex`. And it's nice to not have to deal with two maps.

Comment: Agreed. I implemented it and it fixed my issue. Would you like to claim the answer for this question?

Comment: Sure I will take you up on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't very different from your current plan, but you could save yourself the trouble of handling two maps by using a struct with an embedded mutex for the values of the map.

The struct would look something like this:

```
type SafeItems struct {
    sync.Mutex
    Items []*Item
}
```

And it could be used like this:

```
newMapEntry := SafeItems{Items: itemPtrList}
if result, ok := map.LoadOrStore(key, &newMapEntry); ok {
    mapEntry := result.(*SafeItems)
    mapEntry.Lock()
    mapEntry.Items = append(mapEntry.Items, item)
    mapEntry.Unlock()
}
```

It's not a huge change but it does provide some syntactic sugar.